# How can I repair drywall where it was soaked by a leaking window?

Tags: drywall

[image]

Had windy rainstorm and noticed some water damage. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Fix the drywall or fix the window? I wouldn't deal with the symptom until the cause is eliminated.

Comment: This happened a year ago and we haven't seen the same amount water come in. I suspect a particularly strong wind/rain storm compromised the exterior wall somehow. Still saving up for a window replacement but is compounding over a decent temporary fix?

Comment: I would get a fan on it to help it dry out, I would not try to repair until the leak is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dry things out with fans to prevent mold. Standard joint compound softens when it gets wet, but it's not necessarily bad at that point. Once that's done thoroughly...
2. Cut away all loose material with a utility knife and scraping tool. Any tape that has blistered will need to be replaced. Cut it back to solid attachment.
3. Patch with joint compound and your preferred tape (where needed). Texture to match where necessary.
4. Prime and paint.